# What replacement breaker for a Gould GQF20MB panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a 100amp Gould panel (relevant bits from the label):

> GQF20MB - I-T-E Indoor Loadcenter

> Use only I-T-E Type EQ-P Circuit Breakers

[image]

Since Gould is no longer made under that name, I've gone internet searching, and it *appears* that Siemens Type QP is a suitable replacement. Since I found this info on `<random website>` and I have more confidence in the folks I "know" here, I'd like to confirm that this is a suitable replacement, and if not, what I should be looking for instead.

I need to install a 15a breaker to replace a 20a breaker that some eager but dumb kid installed on 14/2 wire 30 years ago when the internet wasn't around to answer all his questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siemens has 2 lineages of panel: The ex-Murray line and  the ex-ITE line.  Yours is the latter.

I believe the QPs are indeed the right ones.  A Siemens dealer (electrical supply house) could cross-check it in their book to be sure. Or I have a feeling ThreePhaseEel will be along momentarily to same effect :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Siemens QP is correct, but sadly don't have a solid source to back that (too bad JRaef doesn't have a copy of the letter laying around, best I can tell at least...)

Comment: Thank you both (@ThreePhaseEel). Guess I'll have to take the advice I give and call someone other that `<big box store>`. :)